# css: Aligning third button below first two top buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

How do I get the third button below the first two buttons where they are flushed. So the top two buttons are aligned end to end with the third button.

```css
.device-buttons {
  padding: 0em 1em 1em 0em
}
```

```html
<div class="devices">
 <div class="device-buttons">
   <button mat-raised-button
           color="primary"
           [disabled]="hasMaxDevices"
           matTooltip="{{disabledMessage || 'Add a single device'}}"
           (click)="addDevice()">Single Entry</button>&nbsp;
   <button mat-raised-button
           color="primary"
           [disabled]="hasMaxDevices"
           matTooltip="{{disabledMessage || 'Add multiple device'}}"
           (click)="batchDevices()">Batch Entry</button>
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Skip and Search Countries Only</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the first two buttons in a flex-box container and either use `space-between` to justify the content so that the left side of the first button and right side of the second button align with the edges of the third button or set the `flex-grow` property on the buttons in the row to `1` so that they grow to fill the available space.

If using the `space-between` option, make sure to also set the width of the `device-buttons` div to be `fit-content` so that the flex-box only extends to the width of the third button.

Here's an example using `flex-grow`:

```css
.devices {
  width: 20rem; /* for example */
}

.device-buttons {
  --button-spacing: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0em 1em 1em 0em;
}

.top-row {
   margin-bottom: var(--button-spacing);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-row button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.top-row button:first-child {
  margin-right: var(--button-spacing); 
}


.skip-button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="devices">
 <div class="device-buttons">
   <div class="top-row">
     <button mat-raised-button
             color="primary"
             [disabled]="hasMaxDevices"
             matTooltip="{{disabledMessage || 'Add a single device'}}"
             (click)="addDevice()">Single Entry</button>&nbsp;
     <button mat-raised-button
             color="primary"
             [disabled]="hasMaxDevices"
             matTooltip="{{disabledMessage || 'Add multiple device'}}"
             (click)="batchDevices()">Batch Entry</button>
   </div>
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="skip-button">Skip and Search Countries Only</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daniel is this what you were looking for?

Comment: sort of, the first two top buttons have too much of a gap between them, I would like to minimize that gap and also need some space between the top two buttons and that bottom third one.

Comment: also trying to get the buttons to take up the with of the devices class div element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
.device-buttons {
    padding: 0em 1em 1em 0em
}
.device-buttons button:last-child {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

<div class="devices">
 <div class="device-buttons">
   <button mat-raised-button
           color="primary"
           [disabled]="hasMaxDevices"
           matTooltip="{{disabledMessage || 'Add a single device'}}"
           (click)="addDevice()">Single Entry</button>&nbsp;
   <button mat-raised-button
           color="primary"
           [disabled]="hasMaxDevices"
           matTooltip="{{disabledMessage || 'Add multiple device'}}"
           (click)="batchDevices()">Batch Entry</button>
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Skip and Search Countries Only</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so actually a bit of your solution and Henry Woody solution is what has been working, now I am just trying to get the buttons to fill up the width of the devices class div element.